# How many faucet turns does it take for water to flow?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, faucet, bathroom-fixtures

I have the following water outlet for my washing machine:

[image]

Recently, I turned it off after 5 years of non-stop use. A few days later, I cannot open it. I can turn it about 150 degrees, but no more, even if I try as hard as I can.

There are two possible causes for the water not running:

1. There is no water in the pipe leading to this particular faucet — even though all other faucets have water.
2. There is water in the pipe leading to the faucet, but the faucet is faulty.

In order to confirm cause 2. I need to know *if I am turning the faucet enough*.

I don't have this exact faucet anywhere in my house. The closest match is the one leading to the dishwasher, which **turns about 720 degrees** and **water starts coming after maybe 120 degrees of rotation**.

There is no model number, except for the letters **KS** on the bottom of the faucet. However, I don't know what this means, I cannot find any manufacturer called KS. Even so, I don't know if it would help me, since I did not find the 'number of turns' info about any faucet online.

I am hesitating to turn the faucet by force, using a tool, since I am afraid that if I break it off, I will not be able to stop the water.

Comment: Most faucets/taps will start leaking water with a tiny(~10 degrees) and full on between 90 degrees and three or four full turns.  #2 is a good bet, so would look for another faucet/tap(most are similar fittings to supply pipes) and plan on replacement.

Comment: Before messing with this more, make sure that the main water shutoff is accessible and functional.

Comment: Turn it closed again, then open as far as possible, then closed again. Each time, it may well open slightly more as the corroded thread gets woken up. Get a bucket ready for success. And, as Aloysius says, get ready to shoot off to the mains cock, which of course you know will turn off properly first time - don't you..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, it takes about 1/4 turn.

The handle on the faucet is not working.

In your case the handle is just turing by it self, without turning the actual valve, That can happen if the screw is loose, or worse ,the plastic inside the handle is worn out.

No need to turn off water for this.

Try to remove the color cover (with little screwdriver) under it is a screw that holds the handle to the valve. If not just pull the handle upwards.

Unscrew and using a hand or tool open the valve stem, just a 1/4 turn.

Water flows. Inspect the inside of handle (plastic) if anything is broken. It can be easily replaced.

Put it back on and screw it on, now try.

If you have to replace the actual valve **turn water main off**, unscrew it and go to store.

Comment: What black cover?